# Why mosh can stay login even when you changed your network situation?

Tags: mosh

I knew this app in another question on Unix SE.

And it says:

> Change IP. Stay connected.
>
> Mosh automatically roams as you move between Internet connections. Use
>   Wi-Fi on the train, Ethernet in a hotel, and LTE on a beach: you'll
>   stay logged in. Most network programs lose their connections after
>   roaming, including SSH and Web apps like Gmail. Mosh is different.

How could that possible?

Is that a simple reconnect technology?

Comment: Maybe it is like gnu-screen: I login with ssh, I set up as gnu-screen session. I disconnect form ssh. I make a new ssh connection, I connect to gnu-screen session. I go to machine (localy). I connect to gnu-screen session. (So this was all manual, but this could be done automatically).

Comment: The first actual answer, posted 2 hours before that comment answer, shows that it is _not_ like screen.

Answer (score 8):

Mostly because mosh uses a connectionless protocol and properly handles reassociating the client and server.  I'm not 100% certain on the particulars myself, but as I understand it, it works in general like this:

1. When you first use mosh to connect to a remote host, it uses regular SSH to log in as you, and start it's own server component, which listens on a different port for connections.
2. Mosh then closes the original SSH connection, and creates a new terminal session running over its own protocol.  This link uses UDP instead of TCP, so it is functionally emulating a connection on top of a connectionless protocol.
3. If your client's IP address changes, or your network drops out for a while, or something similar happens, mosh tries to re-establish that emulated connection by continuing to send packets to the original server address.  When the server component sees the packets coming in from your new address, it starts sending response packets there instead of your old address.

Of course, there's also authentication involved (otherwise anyone could trivially hijack your mosh sessions), but that's not really particularly important to how the switch happens.

It's probably worth noting that a lot of P2P software uses very similar techniques (that is, essentially equivalent to steps 2 and 3, just with something else being tunneled) to provide resilience against network changes.  Examples of software that does this kind of thing includes [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) and [tinc](http://tinc-vpn.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Your quote comes from the website, https://mosh.org.  If you start reading through "Technical Info", your question is answered :-).

> Is that a simple reconnect technology?

It is not the traditional reconnect technology, i.e. timeout + reconnect.  An example of that would be SSH/TCP timeout + manual reconnect to [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnu_screen) or tmux servers.

`mosh` is purposely designed as mobility technology.  It can adapt much faster.

> Roaming with SSP becomes easy: the client sends datagrams to the server with increasing sequence numbers, including a "heartbeat" at least once every three seconds. Every time the server receives an authentic packet from the client with a sequence number higher than any it has previously received, the IP source address of that packet becomes the server's new target for its outgoing packets. By doing roaming “statelessly” in this manner, roaming works in and out of NATs, even ones that may themselves be roaming. Roaming works even when the client is not aware that its Internet-visible IP address has changed. The heartbeats allow Mosh to inform the user when it hasn't heard from the server in a while (unlike SSH, where users may be unaware of a dropped connection until they try to type).

Other mobility technologies may short-circuit such a heartbeat delay, in cases where the client *is* aware that its Internet-visible IP address has changed.  This section doesn't say whether `mosh` bothers to do so.  Updating after 3 seconds already makes a `mosh` interactive session useful and much more robust than traditional defaults.  Also there are more novel aspects of mosh which "Technical Info" explains, without getting *too* bogged down with the small details :).

At least as described above, `mosh` only implements mobility for one end: the client.  This helps `mosh`, avoiding the need for a third party - unlike Mobile IP which requires a "Home Agent" running on a router with a stable IP address.

When implementing mobility, it is very important that it be controlled securely. `mosh` already includes security initialized through SSH.  Mobile IP does not have this advantage; it looks to leverage IPsec.  IPsec is an optional extension to IP, which you have to configure between your computer and your router.  It tends to only be used in certain narrow scenarios.

There is a third similarity between the use of `mosh` and `screen` or `tmux`: it only works because SSH servers are configured to let you leave a program running indefinitely after disconnecting.  Unless you use `systemd` with the "official" default configuration :).  systemd believes that the lack of ability to control this was a glaring oversight in historical Unix.  Note that in many other scenarios, keeping resources in use indefinitely when you are not even connected would be considered *dangerously* wasteful.  Many Web servers are configured to disconnect clients after a few seconds of not sending or receiving a significant amount of data.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(computer_security)

Mobile IP is an old project.  A much more recent project is MP-TCP (multi-path TCP). It implements simple security for mobility control.  MP-TCP is more similar to `mosh`, in that the initial connection is made to a single server IP which is not mobile.  When the connection is established, it is theoretically possible for either client or server to change their IP address and stay connected.  However it cannot recover if all the IPs change at the same instant.